# win_update "msg": "error: MODULE FAILURE See stdout/stderr for the exact error"

Tags: windows, ansible

I'm trying to run windows updates using win_update with ansible. It's giving me an error but doesn't say what the error exactly is. I'm at a loss

```
ansible-playbook update.yml --tags install -vvvvvv 
ansible-playbook [core 2.16.3]   
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg   
configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']   
ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ansible   
ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections   
executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook   
python version = 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] (/usr/bin/python3)   
jinja version = 3.0.3  libyaml = False 
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file setting up inventory plugins Loading collection ansible.builtin from
```

update.yml

```
`  tasks:

  - name: Reboot if system has a large uptime
    win_reboot:
    when: initial_reboot and not ansible_check_mode
    tags:
    - never
    - reboot

  - block:
    - name: >
        {{ 'Install' if 'install' in ansible_run_tags else 'Search' }} updates
        {{ 'will automatically reboot' if 'reboot' in ansible_run_tags else 'no reboot' }}
      win_updates:
        category_names:
          - SecurityUpdates
          - CriticalUpdates
          - UpdateRollups
          - DefinitionUpdates
          - Updates
        reboot: "{{ 'yes' if 'reboot' in ansible_run_tags else 'no' }}"
        state: "{{ 'installed' if 'install' in ansible_run_tags else 'searched' }}"
      become: yes
      become_method: runas
      become_user: SYSTEM
      register: update_results
      tags:
      - never
      - install
      - check

    rescue:
    - name: Windows update failed?
      debug:
        msg: "error: {{ update_results.msg }}"
      when: update_results is failed and update_results.msg is defined
      tags:
      - always
    - name: Server had pending reboots?
      win_reboot:
      when:  not ansible_check_mode and
            update_results is failed and
            update_results.msg is search('A reboot is required')`
      tags:
          - never
```

Expected Result: updates completed on target host. But I'm facing this error:

```bash
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ansible_collections/ansible/windows/plugins/action/win_updates.py", line 679, in run
    result = self._run_sync(task_vars, module_options, reboot, reboot_timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ansible_collections/ansible/windows/plugins/action/win_updates.py", line 752, in _run_sync
    update_result = self._run_updates(task_vars, module_options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ansible_collections/ansible/windows/plugins/action/win_updates.py", line 848, in _run_updates
    start_result = self._execute_win_updates(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ansible_collections/ansible/windows/plugins/action/win_updates.py", line 946, in _execute_win_updates
    raise _ReturnResultException(msg, exception=result.get('exception', None), **extra_result)

ansible_collections.ansible.windows.plugins.action.win_updates._ReturnResultException: MODULE FAILURE
See stdout/stderr for the exact error

fs01 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed_update_count": 0,
    "filtered_updates": {},
    "found_update_count": 0,
    "installed_update_count": 0,
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 0,
    "updates": {}
}
```

i have successfully win_ping this host so i'm not quite sure where it is failing